# Alternative formation/ notation for axiom of mathematical induction

Tags: logic, induction, first-order-logic, natural-numbers, proof-theory

I hope to clarify the difference between the following two statements:

$S\subset \mathbb{N}$ (set of natural numbers),

1. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \text{ if } n\in S \text{, then } n+1\in S$
2. $\forall n\in S, n+1\in S$

I am currently studying the definition of principles of mathematical induction (PMI). PMI assumes (1.) ([https://www.siue.edu/~jloreau/courses/math-223/notes/sec-induction.html](https://www.siue.edu/%7Ejloreau/courses/math-223/notes/sec-induction.html)) but I am wondering if (2.) means the same thing. They seem to be the same for me.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes they are the same thing; logically equivalent.  The second one just has implicit typing of $n$ as a natural number.  I want to direct you to this interesting cheat sheet I found the other day.  Apparently there are about 10-20 different types of inductive arguments:
https://qcweb.qc.edu.hk/math/Resource/AL/Different%20kinds%20of%20Mathematical%20Induction.pdf

Comment: They are the same, 1 has a redundancy. S is already stipulated to be a subset of $\mathbb N$